# How to add multiple root elements to xml file and use it by appending contents multiple times

Tags: c#, xml, append, xmlwriter

In my case I want to add multiple root nodes to the given xml schema. So I have to append the different user elements with it's child nodes in multiple times by appending with the previous contents in the xml file. My problem is how can I add multiple root elements? (I could add one root element but no idea how to add next ).

This is the xml schema

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SessionId>
  <Scource>
    <User username="AB">
      <DOB>25/5/1980</DOB>
      <FirstName>AVS</FirstName>
      <LastName>WDW</LastName>
      <Location>FWAWE</Location>
    </User>
  <User username="AqB">
    <DOB>25/5/1980</DOB>
    <FirstName>AVS</FirstName>
    <LastName>WDW</LastName>
    <Location>FWAWE</Location>
  </User>
  </Scource>
</SessionId>
```

This is my C# code

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace FilteringNightwing
{
    class Test
    {
         static void Main(string[] args) {

            string fileLocation = "clients.xml";

            if (!File.Exists(fileLocation))
            {
                XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(fileLocation, null);
                writer.WriteStartElement("SessionId");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.Close();

            }

            // Load existing clients and add new 
            XElement xml = XElement.Load(fileLocation);
            xml.Add(new XElement("User",
            new XAttribute("username", "AqB"),
            new XElement("DOB", "25/5/1980"),
            new XElement("FirstName", "AVS"),
            new XElement("LastName", "WDW"),
            new XElement("Location", "FWAWE")));
            xml.Save(fileLocation);

        }

    }
}
```

- How can I add "Source" tag as another root element. All your answers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one root node. Parsing the following will give you an error.

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse("<a></a><b></b>");
```

This will error too:

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse("<a></a><a></a>");
```

If you want multiple children nodes to the root node, that is perfectly fine. You can have nodes with the same name or different. Such as:

```
<a>
  <b />
  <c>
    <d />
  </c>
  <b />
</a>
```

Add new user to `Scource`:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(fileLocation);
XElement scource = xml.Element("Scource"); // Find Scource here
scource.Add(new XElement("User", // Add new user to Scource here
    new XAttribute("username", "AqB"),
    new XElement("DOB", "25/5/1980"),
    new XElement("FirstName", "AVS"),
    new XElement("LastName", "WDW"),
    new XElement("Location", "FWAWE")));
xml.Save(fileLocation);
```

Comment: But in my case structure is not like the one you given. It's like <a><b><c></c><c></c><c></c></b></a>.  How can I do this?

Comment: @OreEraki showed you how in his answer. You find the node you want to add it to, or after, or before, or parent of, etc. Then call the appropriate method with the new `XElement`.

Comment: @user0001 If you want the new user added to the current source (I'll edit my answer)

Comment: Yes I want to add multiple new users in between source. Can you give me the code for that

Comment: @user0001 Your XML has `scource` not `source`. So I made it use what your xml shows.

Comment: when I add your new code I'm getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: @user0001 You need to learn to debug your code. If your XML has `Scource` but you have `Source` in your `Element` call, then it will return null. Your code only does what you tell it to do, not what you *think* you are telling it to do. Compare your XML tags with the strings you are calling. I'm sure you have a request for a tag that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><SessionId><Source></Source></SessionId>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement source = doc.Descendants("Source").FirstOrDefault();

            source.Add(new XElement("User", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("username", "AqB"),
                new XElement("DOB", "25/5/1980"),
                new XElement("FirstName", "AVS"),
                new XElement("LastName", "WDW"),
                new XElement("Location", "FWAWE")
           }));
        }
    }
}
​
```